# Add string "Edit tag info" into transifex

Tags: bug, status-completed, localization, international-sites, transifex

On the [tag page info](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/javascript/info) there is a button to edit tag info.

> [image]

There is no such string in the transifex. Could you add it into transifex, so we will be able to translate it?